# PyQt table Widget Entries to list or numpy array object

Tags: python, user-interface, numpy, pyqt

i am trying to send some data from a gui i am working on to python.
what i want to do ist write a row (gui) to a list (python) or something similar... (directly to a numpy array would be the best)...

my gui has a table widget i created in the QtDesigner i have a python program building this gui:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore  
from Main_window import Ui_Dialog as Dlg

class MyDia(QtGui.QDialog, Dlg): 
    def __init__(self): 
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self) 
        self.setupUi(self)
...
        self.tableWidget.cellChanged.connect(self.cellchanged) #connects a signal when
        #value in cell should be updated
    def cellchanged(self):
        col=self.tableWidget.currentColumn()
        row=self.tableWidget.currentRow()        
        text = self.tableWidget.currentItem().text()
        list=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        list[col]=text
...
```

this is my idea - i want the list (or array) to be updated/changed when the user has has changed the entry of a cell. I have only one row so it does not have to be a 2D array.

I need this cause i am sending an array to my actual calculation program where "list" is an input:

```
...    exec(open("./calculation.py").read())
```

or

```
...    from calculator import calc
       calc(list)
```

i hope someone can help me with this...

Comment: If you installed spyder, you can use `spyderlib.widgets.arrayeditor` to do this.

Comment: What is your actual question? I understand what you are trying to do, but don't understand what specific problem you are asking for help with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to use a "numpy" array i succeded- i changed the "cellchanged" section
and defined a button the user has to click after he has input all the cells

"tableWidget" is the object name defined in QtDesigner or the "..." section
    import numpy as np
    from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
    from Main_window import Ui_Dialog as Dlg

```
class MyDia(QtGui.QDialog, Dlg): 
    def __init__(self): 
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
... 
        self.setupUi(self)
self.connect(self.buttonOK, 
                QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.onOK)# the button signal
    def onOK(self):#event when user clicks
        list=np.zeros((1,16))
        for i in range(0,16,1):               
               list[0,i]= float(self.tableWidget.item(0,i).text())
               #reads in the first row the User has input before
```

thanks anyway guys!